# Debugging a script for a game engine

Tags: c++, parsing, dll, scripting, game-engine

Hello I created a scripting system for my game engine and I wish to know if there is any way to debug it in runtime. The basic principle in how the scripting system works is that a new project is created and it uses a reference to the engine code so you can use the functions provided by it. It then exports the script as a dll and the engine reads that and uses the script in the engine. I don't know how I would do something like a breakpoint in there though.

ScriptManager.h:

```
#define RegisterScript(className) extern "C" {__declspec(dllexport) Script* CreateScript(){ return new className(); } }

    struct GameObject;

    class DLL_API ScriptManager {
    private:
        static size_t scriptAmount;
        static double timeElapsed;

        static bool loadDllFromFolder(const std::string& path, const bool& supressError);

    public:
        static std::unordered_map<size_t, std::string> numberToPath;
        static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> scriptPathToName;
        static std::unordered_map<std::string, GameObject* (__stdcall*)()> scriptNameToScript;
        static std::unordered_map<std::string, HINSTANCE> scriptNameToHandle;

        static void loadScriptFromDLL(const std::string& path, const std::string& name, const bool& supressError);
        static void init();
        static void close();
        static void update();
        static void checkForScripts(const bool& supressError);
        //static size_t getAmountOfScripts();
        static GameObject* instantiateScript(const std::string& name);
        static bool checkScript(const std::string& name);

    };
```

ScriptManager.cpp:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> ScriptManager::scriptPathToName{};
    std::unordered_map<std::string, GameObject* (__stdcall*)()> ScriptManager::scriptNameToScript{};
    std::unordered_map<size_t, std::string> ScriptManager::numberToPath{0};
    std::unordered_map<std::string, HINSTANCE> ScriptManager::scriptNameToHandle{};

    size_t ScriptManager::scriptAmount = 1;
    double ScriptManager::timeElapsed = 0;


    void ScriptManager::loadScriptFromDLL(const std::string& path, const std::string& _name, const bool& supressError) {

        HINSTANCE dllHandle = LoadLibraryA(path.c_str());

        if (!dllHandle) {
            Debug::systemErr("Couldn't load dll file containing scripts at: " + path);
        }

        typedef GameObject* (__stdcall* scriptPointer)();

        scriptPointer createScript = (scriptPointer)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "CreateScript");

        if (!createScript) {
            Debug::systemErr("Couldn't find the create function of a script in the dll file containing scripts at: " + path + "(Check if there is an export function for the script)");
        }

        std::string name = _name.substr(0, _name.length() - 4);

        if (scriptPathToName.find(path) == scriptPathToName.end() && scriptNameToScript.find(name) == scriptNameToScript.end()) {
            scriptPathToName[path] = name;
            numberToPath[scriptAmount] = path;
            scriptNameToScript[name] = createScript;
            scriptNameToHandle[name] = dllHandle;

            Debug::systemSuccess("Loaded script: " + name, DebugColor::Blue);
            scriptAmount += 1;
        }
        else {
            if(!supressError)
            Debug::systemErr("Already loaded script file: " + path + ", or already loaded script with name: " + name);
        }
    }

    void ScriptManager::init() {
        checkForScripts(false);
    }

    void ScriptManager::update() {
        ProfileMethod("ScriptManager update");
        timeElapsed += Time::getDeltaTime();

        if (timeElapsed >= HFR_SCRIPT_MANAGER_UPDATE_DELAY) {
            timeElapsed = 0;
            checkForScripts(true);
        }
    }

    void ScriptManager::checkForScripts(const bool& supressError) {
        
        if(!loadDllFromFolder(HFR_SCRIPTS, supressError))
            Debug::systemErr("Couldn't load scripts folder wtf");
    }

    void ScriptManager::close() {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < scriptAmount; i++) {
            FreeLibrary(scriptNameToHandle[scriptPathToName[numberToPath[i]]]);
            Debug::systemSuccess("Deleted script: " + scriptPathToName[numberToPath[i]], DebugColor::Blue);
        }
    }

    GameObject* ScriptManager::instantiateScript(const std::string& name) {
        if (scriptNameToScript.find(name) != scriptNameToScript.end()) {
            return scriptNameToScript[name]();
        }
        else {
            Debug::systemErr("No script found of name: " + name);
            return nullptr;
        }
    }

    bool ScriptManager::checkScript(const std::string& name) {
        return (scriptNameToScript.find(name) != scriptNameToScript.end());
    }

    bool ScriptManager::loadDllFromFolder(const std::string& path, const bool& supressError) {
        DIR* dir;

        struct dirent* ent;

        if ((dir = opendir(path.c_str())) != NULL) {

            while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
                std::string file = ent->d_name;

                if (file.find(".") != std::string::npos) {
                    if (file.find(".dll") != std::string::npos) {

#ifdef _DEBUG
                        if (file.substr(file.find(".dll") - 2, 2) == "_D")
                            loadScriptFromDLL(path + file, file, supressError);
                        else if (!supressError && file.substr(file.find(".dll") - 2, 2) != "_R")
                            Debug::systemErr("Couldn't load script dll: " + file + ", because it doesn't have debug identification, it should be: scriptname_D.dll. At path: " + path);
#else
                        if (file.substr(file.find(".dll") - 2, file.find(".dll")) == "_R")
                            loadScriptFromDLL(path + file, file, supressError);
                        else if (!supressError)
                            Debug::systemErr("Couldn't load script dll: " + file + ", because it doesn't have release identification, it should be: scriptname_R.dll. At path: " + path);
#endif
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //we have found a folder or a blank file
                    loadDllFromFolder(path + file + "/", supressError);
                }

            }

            closedir(dir);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Here is a basic script that I made,
testscript.h (auto generated):

```
namespace testProject{

    class testScript : public Script {
    public:
        void start();
        void update();
        void fixedUpdate();
        void lateUpdate();
        void stop();
    };
    RegisterScript(testScript)

}
```

testscript.cpp:

```
#include "testScript.h"
using namespace HFR;

namespace testProject{

    void testScript::start() {
        Debug::log("start");
        //how do i put a breakpoint here?
    }

    void testScript::update() {

    }

    void testScript::fixedUpdate() {

    }

    void testScript::lateUpdate() {

    }

    void testScript::stop() {

    }

}
```

If your wondering this is where the script gets put into the gameobject:

```
struct DLL_API NativeScript {
        std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::string> nameToScriptIndex{};
        unsigned int scriptAmount = 0;

        std::array<GameObject*, HFR_MAX_SCRIPTS> scripts{nullptr};

        void (*instantiateScript)(NativeScript*, const unsigned int&) = {};

        //name is the name of the dll file in which the script is in
        void addScript(const std::string& name) {
            if (ScriptManager::checkScript(name)) {
                nameToScriptIndex[scriptAmount] = name;
                scriptAmount += 1;
            }
            else
                Debug::systemErr("Couldn't add script with name: " + name + ", because it wasn't registered");
            
            instantiateScript = [](NativeScript* nativeScript, const unsigned int& index) {
                GameObject* script = ScriptManager::instantiateScript(nativeScript->nameToScriptIndex[index]);
                if (script != nullptr)
                    nativeScript->scripts[index] = script;
                else
                    Debug::systemErr("Couldn't find script: " + nativeScript->nameToScriptIndex[index]);
            };
        }

        void destroyScripts() {

        }

    };
```

Then I would just call instantiateScript and it would run the stored instantiateScript function.

Comment: Most debuggers had an "attach to process" option. Attach to the game process, place a breakpoint on the code you wish to inspect, and wait for the code to be called by the game engine..

Comment: @user4581301 i was able to successfully attach to the process and place a breakpoint in the script to stop it, do you know how i would be able to do this automatically? instead of doing ctrl + alt + p and selecting the game engine.

Comment: the debugger should be able to run any program. See if you can convince the debugger to run your game engine directly.